# Redirecting customers to different pages based on customer group

Tags: magento-1.9, login, redirect

I have been asked how much work this would be to do, I assume I would need to edit the `AccountController.php` 
But before I even start I am wondering if anyone knows first if possible and second how much work would it actually be to be able to control my 5 customer groups and give them each specific redirects?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with `AccountController.php`. There're also events that you can observe to make this happens.

One thing that I would look into is other place where customer can log-in (for example if customer choose to log-in on the checkout page you would want to redirect them back to the checkout page instead of elsewhere). But this is depends on the business application.